# Toggles Trait execute and query voice commands fail in Spanish

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I've been developing a Smart Home Action which uses Toggles Trait. Everything works fine in English but when I try to execute "*turn off*" commands in Spanish (customers' predominant language) the Assistant doesn't seem to understand them. It only happens with turn off (desactivar/apagar) commands. Moreover, Spanish syntax that works for triggering the QUERY intent is not correct as any user would talk like that.

Here's a list of EXECUTE command examples in both languages with their result:

1. **Turn on** *<toggle_name>* on <*device_name*> (english) --> **OK**

   **Enciende** *<toggle_name>* en <*device_name*> (spanish) --> **OK**
2. **Activate** <*toggle_name*> on <*device_name*> (english) --> **OK**

   **Activa** <*toggle_name*> en <*device_name*> (spanish) --> **OK**
3. **Turn off** <*toggle_name*> on <*device_name*> (english) --> **OK**

   **Apaga** <*toggle_name*> **en** <*device_name*> (spanish) --> **FAIL** "Sorry, I don't understand you"

   **Apaga** <*toggle_name*> **on** <*device_name*> (spanish) --> **OK** "Spanish syntax error. "*on*" is an English preposition, for Spanish we use "*en*".
4. **Deactivate** <*toggle_name*> on <*device_name*> (english) --> **OK**

   **Desactiva** <*toggle_name*> en <*device_name*> (spanish) --> **FAIL** "Sorry, I don't understand you"

   **Desactiva** <*toggle_name*> **on** <*device_name*> (spanish) --> **OK** But this is a Spanish syntax error. "*on*" is an English preposition, in Spanish we use "*en*".

Here's a list of QUERY command examples in both languages with their result:

1. **Is** <*device_name*> <toggle_name> **on**? (english) --> **OK**

   **Está** la opción <*toggle_name*> **encendido** en el/la <*device_name*>? (spanish) --> **FAIL**

   **Está** el modo <*toggle_name*> **encendido** en el/la <*device_name*>? (spanish) --> **FAIL**

   <*toggle_name*> la <*device_room*> **está encendido**? (spanish) --> **OK** But horrible syntax, not natural.

   <*toggle_name*> la <*device_name*> **está encendido**? (spanish) --> **FAIL** Althouh is similar to previous syntax.
2. **Is** <*device_name*> <toggle_name> **off**? (english) --> **OK**

   **Está** la opción <*toggle_name*> **encendido** en el/la <*device_name*>? (spanish)  --> **FAIL**

   **Está** el modo <*toggle_name*> **encendido** en el/la <*device_name*>? (spanish) --> **FAIL**

   <*toggle_name*> la <*device_room*> **está apagado**? (spanish) --> **FAIL** Althouh is the horrible syntax that previously worked.

Here's an example of SYNC intent code for adding toggle trait:

```
availableToggles: [
    {
        name: "photocaller_toggle",
        name_values: [
            {
            name_synonym: [
                "Photocaller",
                "photo caller",
                "photocall",
                "Auto foto",
                "fotos",
                "foto automática"
            ],
            "lang": "es"
            },
            {
            name_synonym: [
                "Photocaller",
                "photo caller",
                "photocall",
                "photos",
                "auto photo",
                "automatic photo"
            ],
            lang: "en"
            }
        ]
    },
],
commandOnlyToggles: false,
queryOnlyToggles: false,
```

Is there a possible solution to fix this? Or anyway to tell Google so they are aware of it?

Answer (score 0):

Please file this information through the [public bug tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148).